# Why Use Synchronized Methods for Animation?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation

I've been reading, The Beginner's Guide to Android Game Development - James Cho and he uses a synchronized method for an animation class (a compilation of frames). This animation will be run inside the game loop, a thread. My question is, why is it necessary to have these `Animation` methods synchronized if it is only the main and game loop thread?

```
package com.jamescho.framework.animation;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Animation {

    private Frame[] frames;
    private double[] frameEndTimes;
    private int currentFrameIndex = 0;
    private double totalDuration = 0;
    private double currentTime = 0;

    public Animation(Frame... frames) {

        this.frames = frames;
        frameEndTimes = new double[frames.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {

            Frame f = frames[i];

            totalDuration += f.getDuration();

            frameEndTimes[i] = totalDuration;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void update(float increment) {

        currentTime += increment;

        if (currentTime > totalDuration) {

            wrapAnimation();
        }

        while (currentTime > frameEndTimes[currentFrameIndex]) {

            currentFrameIndex++;
        }

    }

    private synchronized void wrapAnimation() {

        currentFrameIndex = 0;
        currentTime %= totalDuration; // equal to cT = cT % tD      
    }


    public synchronized void render(Graphics g, int x, int y) {

        g.drawImage(frames[currentFrameIndex].getImage(), x, y, null);      
    }

    public synchronized void render(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height){

        g.drawImage(frames[currentFrameIndex].getImage(), x, y, width, height, null);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one thread (for example the main/UI thread and another background thread), there is a chance that at some point different threads might try to run the same method at the same time with unexpected and (sometimes/often) undesirable consequences.

Comment: I see that could be a possibility, however, the main thread doesn't call this method so how could it interfere with it?

Comment: If there is only one thread that is calling the method and there is no way for a second method to simultaneously call it, then you wouldn't need to worry about the synchronization and there is no need as you suggested. It is your code so you are the one who needs to make the call. If you just copy/pasted it from somewhere else, maybe in their case multithreading was needed (or was coded for future-proofing.)

Comment: The problem isn't with multiple threads executing the same *method*, it's with multiple threads reading and writing the same *fields*. All of those methods access certain fields (e.g. `currentFrameIndex`). If any method can be called from a different thread, some form of synchronization is required.

Comment: @fadden I think that is the case. Thank you very much. Create an answer if you like.